# I want python to skip the list if it doesn't have more than 3 parts (space separated) while reading a file line

Tags: python, list

I'm making python read one file that makes all the lines of a file as a space-separated list current I'm facing an issue where I want python to read a list only if the content is more than 3 parts
I'm trying `if int(len(list[3])) == 3:` then read the 3 parts of the list but the program is giving the error of

> `IndexError: list index out of range

it is usually given when I access something that doesn't exist but the line of code that read the 3rd part shouldn't run on a list without 3+ parts

Comment: `list[3]` tries to get the 4th element from the list `list` (which is a bad name for a var if you're actually using that)... it will give index error if there are not at least 4 elements in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```py
if len(list) > 3:
    # read list
```

1. You don't need to convert `len()` to an int - it already is an int
2. `list[3]` gives you back fourth element of the **list**, you need to pass whole **list** object to `len` function
3. `int == 3` will only catch numbers equal to 3, while you wanted all numbers above 3

Answer (score 1):

I think is this:

```py
def get_file_matrix(file:str):
    with open(file,'r') as arq:
        lines = arq.readlines()
        #saniting 
        lines_clear = list(map(lambda line:line.strip(),lines))
        lines_splited = list(map(lambda line:line.split(' '),lines_clear))
        lines_filtered = list(filter(lambda line: len(line) <= 3,lines_splited    ) )
        return lines_filtered


r = get_file_matrix('test.txt')
print(r)
```